# Defining a function prototype in C++ based on requirement

Tags: c++, c, pointers, function-pointers, function-prototypes

I'm having a disagreement with my professor about the following function prototype:

Prompt: "function that takes pointer to a float, a pointer to a pointer to a char and returns a pointer to a pointer to a integer."

I say it is

`int ** function(float * myFloat, char ** myChar)`

but the options given are:

```
A. int **fun(float **, char**)  
B. int *fun(float*, char*)  
C. int ***fun(float*, char**)  
D. int ***fun(*float, **char)
```

none of which I think are correct. To be clear, I'm not asking for a solution - I'm posting my function prototype to show that I THINK I know the solution and have worked through it.

Is it possible that any of the options given are correct? I'd love to be proven wrong and told that one of the solutions is possible (again, don't tell me which is correct if any are possible)

Comment: You are correct, but what does your professor say?  I'm wondering if there's a communication breakdown over the actual problem, expectations, etc....

Comment: He said "Please read the problem carefully and answer it exactly as required."

Comment: Once had a test where the last question had me working right up to the last minute on an insanely hard problem. With the exception of another few classmates who I later found were the better programmers in the program, the rest of the class had handed in their test papers and left close to an hour earlier. I figured they'd all given up on the problem and left. The professor later apologized because he'd screwed up the question and those of us who spent hours working on it caught an unintended subtlety that made the problem much harder than intended. Professors screw up sometimes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, and none of the 4 suggested answers matches what is stated in the prose.